# Converted a code from javascript to python, tryin to use Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

The code under does not draw any image:
"""

```
import turtle 
import numpy as np

turtle = turtle.Turtle()
steps = 24000
size = 61

def walk(i):
    turtle.penup()
    term =  1.0357902468 * 2 * np.pi * i/steps
    turtle.goto(size * np.sin(term), size * np.cos(term))
    turtle.pendown()
    len = 5+2.5*np.sin(0.5 * np.pi + term)*np.cos(0.5 * np.pi + term)
    l = 0.02
    if l < len:
        turtle.right(np.sin(l + steps/8 * term))
        turtle.forward(l)
        l = l * 1.01
    return i < steps

i=2
walk(i)
"""
```

Does it just not work and is unfixable, or is there something i am missing?

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with the issue?

Comment: Please don't include irrelevant tags. Just because the original code was in JavaScript, it doesn't mean that this is a JavaScript question.

Comment: It was in javascript format, i thought maybe i made a mistake when changing it

Comment: It seems like you walk `0.02` pixels and return

Comment: What is the purpose of `l = l * 1.01` when you don't use that variable anymore? The variable names seem to suggest you want some sort of looping, but there is no loop in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my eye, it seems like you used an `if` when you meant a `while`.  Making that substitution, and tidying up the code, it does draw something:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import sin, cos, pi

STEPS = 24000
SIZE = 61

def walk(i):
    turtle.penup()
    term = 1.0357902468 * 2 * pi * i/STEPS
    turtle.goto(SIZE * sin(term), SIZE * cos(term))
    turtle.pendown()

    length = 5 + 2.5 * sin(pi/2 + term) * cos(pi/2 + term)
    l = 0.02

    while l < length:
        turtle.right(sin(l + STEPS/8 * term))
        turtle.forward(l)
        l *= 1.01

    return i < STEPS

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

walk(2)  # return value ignored

screen.exitonclick()
```

The next question to ponder is whether you're expecting `right()` to operate in degrees (the default) or radians (an option) which JavaScript uses.

Comment: Well, it might be in radians as the output was not as expected, nevertheless thank you!

Comment: @MatteoSevenius, add `turtle.radians()` after the `turtle` instance creation to switch it away from degrees.